# Terraform - precondition on list items

Tags: terraform

In my terraform code, I'm using a lifecycle precondition to validate a variable:

```
lifecycle {
  precondition {
    condition     = can(regex("foo-bar-regex", each.value))
    error_message = "foo-bar error"
  }
}
```

This works well if `each.value` is a simple string.

However, how can I do the same if `each.value` is a list (`['foo', 'bar']`) and I want to validate each item of it? i.e check that `foo` matches the regex and `bar` too.
Is it even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `alltrue` function and a `for` expression for this:

```
condition = alltrue([for var_element in each.value : can(regex("foo-bar-regex", var_element))])
```